# Trouble splitting text without using split()

Tags: python, string, split

> *splitText*(*text*) where *text* is a string and return the list of the words by splitting the string *text*. 
>   See example below:
>
> > > sampleText = "As Python's creator, I'd like to say a few words about its origins.”
> > >
> > > splitText(sampleText)
> > >
> > > > ['As', 'Python', 's', 'creator', 'I', 'd', 'like', 'to', 'say', 'a', 'few', 'words', 'about', 'its', 'origins']
>
> You must NOT use the method split() from the str type, however other methods >from the class are allowed. You must not use python library such as string.py.

This is my code:

```
def split(text):
    final_lst = ""
    length = len(text)
    for x in range(length):
        if text[x].isalpha() == True:
            final_lst = final_lst + text[x]
        else:
            final_lst = final_lst + ", "

    final_len = len(final_lst)
    for a in range(final_len):
        if final_lst[:a] == " " or final_lst[:a] == "":
            final_lst = "'" + final_lst[a]
        if final_lst[a:] == " " or final_lst[a:] == ", ":
            final_lst = final_lst[a] + "'"
        elif final_lst[:a].isalpha() or final_lst[a:].isalpha():
            final_lst[a]


    print(final_lst)

split(sampleText)
```

When I run it I get this:

> > > 'A

I've tried lots of things to try and solve.

Comment: The exercise is not overly clear on what characters the string is to be split (apparently, not on a '.'), and it looks like adjacent splitting characters are not to be split (the comma-space sequence doesn't introduce an empty string).

Comment: @Evert don't you mean "Make final_lst = [] an empty list"?

Comment: @whitebeard: correct, slip of the keyboard. Since I'm outside the edit grace period, adding the corrected comment anew.

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way: you have to build up a *list*, not a new string with `", "` as separator. The example result given is just the string representation of that list. Make `final_lst = []` an empty list, then append each substring to it. Don't use separator strings like `", "` etc. For the substring, just loop over the current position in your input string until `isalpha` is `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your function name is wrong. You have `split(text)` and the exercise specifically calls for `splitText(text)`. If your class is graded automatically, for example by a program that just loads your code and tries to run `splitText()`, you'll fail.

Next, this would be a good time for you to learn that a string is an iterable object in Python. You don't have to use an index - just iterate through the characters directly.

```
for ch in text:
```

Next, as @Evert pointed out, you are trying to build a list, not a string. So use the correct Python syntax:

```
final_list = []
```

Next, let's think about how you can process one character at a time and get this done. When you see a character, you can determine whether it is, or is not, an alphabetic character. You need one more piece of information: what were you doing before?

- If you are in a "word", and you get "more word", you can just append it.
- If you are in a "word", and you get "not a word", you have reached the end of the word and should add it to your list.
- If you are in "not a word", and you get "not a word", you can just ignore it.
- If you are in "not a word", and you get "word", that's the start of a new word.

Now, how can you tell whether you are in a word or not? Simple. Keep a word variable.

```
def splitText(text):
    """Split text on any non-alphabetic character, return list of words."""
    final_list = []
    word = ''

    for ch in text:
        if word:   # Empty string is false!
            if ch.isalpha():
                word += ch
            else:
                final_list.append(word)
                word = ''
        else:
            if ch.isalpha():
                word += ch
            else:
                # still not alpha. 
                pass

    # Handle end-of-text with word still going
    if word:
        final_list.append(word)

    return final_list

sampleText = "As Python's creator, I'd like to say a few words about its origins."
print(splitText(sampleText))
```

Output is:

> ['As', 'Python', 's', 'creator', 'I', 'd', 'like', 'to', 'say', 'a', 'few', 'words', 'about', 'its', 'origins']

Next, if you sit and stare at it for a while you'll realize that you can combine some of the cases. It boils down nicely- try turning it inside out by moving the outer if to the inside, and see what you get.

Comment: Nice detailed answer. One problem I think (and everyone else has made it too) is you don't handle the string ending with a word and no separator.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you are complicating things too much, basically all you need to do is to go through the text char by char, and combining them to words, once you find empty space you separate it and add it to the result array. After you run out of text you just return the array.

```
def splittext(text):
   result = []
   word = ""
   for i in text:
       if i != " ":
           word += i
       else:
           result.append(word)
           word = ""
   result.append(word)
   return result
```

Comment: This does not account for the apostrophes which the example clearly indicates should also be a split point.

Comment: You should use `if not i.isalpha()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

smapleText = 'As Python\'s creator, I\'d like to say a few words about its origins.'

```
def split(text):
   result =[]
   temp=""
   length = len(text)
   for x in range(length):
      if text[x].isalpha():
         temp = temp+text[x]
      else:
         result.append(temp)
         temp=""

      print result

split(smapleText)
```

Comment: Consider what happens if the text contains two non-alpha characters. (Like a punctuation mark and a quote.)

Comment: I just provided a step in solving the problem. He will have to do the lexical analysis as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you cheat with regular expressions?

```
import re
sampleText = "As Python's creator, I'd like to say a few words about its origins."
result = re.findall(r'\w+', sampleText)

>>> result
['As', 'Python', 's', 'creator', 'I', 'd', 'like', 'to', 'say', 'a', 'few', 'words', 'about', 'its', 'origins']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringSplitter(string):
    words = []
    current_word = ""
    for x in range(len(string)):
        if string[x] == " ":
            words.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
        else:
            current_word += string[x]
    return words
```